# $K \subset E \subset L$ finite field extensions and $L$ normal over $K$. Is $L$ normal over $E$, and is $E$ normal over $K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

**Question:** $K \subset E \subset L$ finite field extensions and $L$ normal over $K$.
**(a)** Is $L$ normal over $E$?
**(b)** Is $E$ normal over $K$?

So far, I believe I have done **(b)** (see below) but am stuck on **(a)**.

---

**My answer for (a):** Take $l \in L$ and let $P_K(X) \in K[X]$ and $P_E(X) \in E[X]$ be its minimal polynomials over $K$ and $E$ respectively.

$L/K$ is normal $\implies$ $P_K(X)$ splits in $L[X]$. $P_K(l)=0$ and $P_E(X)$ generates the ideal of all polynomials in $E[X]$ such that $P_E(l)=0$, therefore $P_E(X)$ divides $P_K(X)$.

Therefore,  $P_E(X)$ splits completely in $L[X]$ so $L/E$ is a normal extension.

---

**My idea for (b)**: If this were false, and $E/K$ is not a normal extension, then I could prove this by finding a counter-example. e.g: $L=\mathbb{Q}(A, B)$, $E=\mathbb{Q}(A)$ and $K=\mathbb{Q}$.

I have not made any progress with this method and would appreciate some help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try letting $L$ be the splitting field of, say, $x^3-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have answered part (a) in what you state is your answer to part (b), anyway, for part (b), ie. is E normal over K:

let K = $\mathbb{Q}$, L = The splitting field of $x^3 - 2$ and E = $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ (ie. $\mathbb{Q}/(x^2-3)$ or equivalently $\mathbb{Q}$ with one of the roots of $x^3 - 2$ adjoined)

Now K $\subset$ E $\subset$ L and L is normal over K (as it is a splitting field)

The 3 roots of $x^3 - 2$ are $\sqrt[3]{2}$, $\sqrt[3]{2}\omega$ and $\sqrt[3]{2}\omega^2$ where $\omega$ is the complex cube root of unity  ($\omega^3 = 1$)

but $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is the only one which is in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$  (can you see why?)

Thus $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is not normal over $\mathbb{Q}$

and so E is not normal over K in general